# Problem with `tidyr`'s function `extract`

Tags: r, tidyr

I've been using `tidyr`'s function `extract`for some time successfully but can no longer get it to work. Here's a simple toy case, where I want to separate `full_name` into `First_name` and `Second_name`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  full_name = c("Peter Paul", "Mike Scott")
)
```

Using `extract`, however, throws an error:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  extract(col = full_name, into = c("First_name", "Second_Name"), regex = "(.*)\\s(.*)")
Error in stopifnot(is.numeric(maxDist), maxDist >= 0, length(pattern) ==  : 
  argument "pattern" is missing, with no default
```

The problem seems not to be due to the regex; I can't get `extract` to run with other data with proven regex either!

Comment: You are probably using `extract` from another package. Try `tidyr::extract(df, col = full_name, into = c("First_name", "Second_Name"), regex = "(.*)\\s(.*)")`

Comment: @RonakShah `stringdist::extract` reproduce same error :D

Comment: Oh okay, so `extract`does not work inside `dplyr`?

Comment: It works but I think your default `extract` is now `stringdist::extract` not `tidyr::extract`.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `read.table` from `base R`

```
read.table(text = df$full_name, header = FALSE, col.names = c("First_name", "Second_name"))
  First_name Second_name
1      Peter        Paul
2       Mike       Scott
```